# Calculate multiple select dropdown

Tags: jquery, math, multiple-select

I have a multiple selection menu like so:

```
<select style="width:345px;" multiple="multiple" id="syndicate_group">
    <option data-cost="10" value="groupNo114">Starter</option>
    <option data-cost="15" value="groupNo100">Bronze</option>
    <option data-cost="25" value="groupNo104">Silver</option>
    <option data-cost="34" value="groupNo108">Gold</option>
    <option data-cost="0" value="groupNo115">Other</option>
</select>

<input type="number" placeholder="" value="" name="ammountToPay" id="ammountToPayField">
```

I want to do a calculation based on the **data-cost** and not the value of user selection, so if the user selects both Starter and Bronze, the value in the id of **'ammountToPayField'** will be 25, but then if they decide they only want bronze, the value in **'ammountToPayField'** will only be 15 but having looked for a while I can only find input fields and not a multiple select field.

Comment: You'll probably want to take a look into check boxes as appose to a drop down select if you want to select multiple options.

Comment: sorry guys I just had to change it from calculation based on value to that of data-cost attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#syndicate_group').change(function() {
    var sum = $(this).find(':checked')
                     .map(function() { return parseInt($(this).data('cost'), 10); })
                     .get()
                     .reduce(function(x, y) { return x + y; });

    $('#ammountToPayField').val(sum);
});
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1bg43xfe/1/)

Comment: thanks, this works great but sorry i found out i need to calculate using data-cost not the value, can you ammend because parseInt(this.data('cost'), 10); }) doesn't work instead of your parseInt(this.value, 10); })

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#syndicate_group").change(function () {
var sum = 0;
$("select option:selected").each(function() {
  sum += parseInt($(this).text());
});
$( "#ammountToPayField" ).text( sum ); }).change();
```